# What are the main differences between set theory versus pure type systems?

Tags: set-theory, type-theory

According to wikipedia, a [pure type system:](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pure_type_system)

> ...is a form of typed lambda calculus that allows an arbitrary number
>   of sorts and dependencies between any of these... Pure type systems
>   may obscure the distinction between types and terms and collapse the type hierarchy.

This sounds an awful lot like material set theory. What are the (main) differences?

Comment: The Wikipedia article is short on details. Have you looked at the [nLab article](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/pure+type+system)?